# How can i recover item into master database if deleted accidentally?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have recently started working on sitecore,
I accidentally deleted an item from **master database** now i want to recover that item.
i am trying move functionality of sitecore but didn't get any chance for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore provides item and subitems **transfer** functionality, through which we can move any item from one database to another like web to master.

[image]

for more information : 
http://sitecoresolution.blogspot.in/2015/01/sitecore-move-items-from-web-to-master.html

Comment: Just be careful when you transfer items from the web database to the master database because you WILL lose all the version history.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all deleted items in the "Recycle Bin"

[image: Recycle Bin]

To restore an item, open the recycle bin, select your item and click "Restore"

[image: Restore]

Comment: The major problem of this approach is that we cant select sub-items or multiple items at a time.